# Loading a View programatically in to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have 2 questions actually. First I'll explain the scenario. I have a simple Storyboard app. The first controller is a `UITableViewController` displaying a list of mail types. When tapped upon a cell, it segues to a `UIViewController` and depending on the selected mail type, it loads a `UIView` into the `UIViewController`. This is all working fine. My problems are,

One `UIView` I have is 559 in height. I put a `UIScrollView` inside the `UIViewController` so that when the `UIView` with the extra height is loaded, it'll be scrollable. But instead of that happening, the `UIView` resizes to the size of the `UIViewController`. How can I keep its original height and embed it inside a `UIScrollView`?
From the Interface builder, I've put a `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the `UIViewController`. But when the `UIView` is loaded into it, the `UIToolbar` disappears. I guess the `UIView` appears on top of the `UIToolbar`(?). How can I avoid this from happening?

I know this must a bit confusing to understand. Therefore I've uploaded an Xcode project demonstrating the 2 issues [here](http://www14.zippyshare.com/v/50134738/file.html).

Please have a look and tell me what I should do.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details about which "mail type" has which problem. I see "Project memo" shows a view with what looks like a tool bar at the bottom. Which "mail type" gives the issue with height and scrolling?

Comment: Its the **Email** mail type. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems with what you're doing in your project that may explain why you're getting these results.

1. In `NewMailViewController.m`, you are replacing the view you've created in the storyboard (the one that has a scroll view and a toolbar) with the one you've loaded from the nib (i.e. `self.view = [nib objectAtIndex:0];`). Try doing this in -loadView

   ```
   [super loadView];

   UIView *someView = nil;

   if ([self.mailTypeName isEqualToString:@"Email"]) {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Email" owner:self options:nil];
       someView = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   else if ([self.mailTypeName isEqualToString:@"Facsimile"]) {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Facsimile" owner:self options:nil];
       someView = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   else if ([self.mailTypeName isEqualToString:@"Memorandum"]) {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Memorandum" owner:self options:nil];
       someView = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   else if ([self.mailTypeName isEqualToString:@"ProjectMemo"]) {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProjectMemo" owner:self options:nil];
       someView = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }

   CGRect frame = someView.frame;
   frame.size.width = self.myScrollView.frame.size.width;
   [someView setFrame: frame];

   [self.myScrollView addSubview: someView];
   [self.myScrollView setContentSize: someView.bounds.size];
   ```
2. You'll notice that I have a reference to the scroll view in the above snippet of code. You'll want to create an outlet for the scroll view in your `NewMailViewController` class so that you can refer to it as needed. It involves putting this in your header file:

   `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;`

   You'll need to connect the defined outlet to the actual storyboard's scroll view. You can search for "creating or connecting outlets in Xcode" on the Internet for more information about that.
3. The toolbar appears to be a subview of the scroll view. Don't you want the toolbar to rest at the bottom of the view while the content of the scroll view scrolls? If so, you'll want to move that toolbar view out from within the scroll view.

Here are the changes: http://www62.zippyshare.com/v/90505016/file.html